# Constant variance and increasing mean of residuals in regression

Tags: regression, residuals, heteroscedasticity

I am trying a to fit a regression model but the residual plot shows abnormality. The variance of the residuals variance is about constant but the mean is increasing.

[image: residual analysis plots]

As per my knowledge heteroskedasticity means constant mean and increasing variance but in my case the observation is opposite of this. I am not sure of what this problem is and why this problem arise?

Comment: The charts are an indication of a poor predictor overall (it is not very good at predicting different actual values).  For judging heteroskedasticity you should be looking at the second chart and, given how much overlapping data there is, it is difficult to judge visually whether it is showing a constant mean or not (and whether or not that mean is $0$)

Comment: The first graph does not indicate any problem.  The residuals are always correlated with the actual values, so an "increase in mean" in that graph does not raise any alarms.

Comment: @BigBendRegion a slope on the first chart close to $1$ may say something about the usefulness of the model